Python: how to get an event from child class
I display a video and want to enable zoom.
My MainWindow has a slider for the zoom, and a "Display" widget, which is a custom QGraphicsView.
My MainWindow setup and trigger the camera, and send the image and the "zoom value" to the "display" like this:
@pyqtSlot(QImage)
def on_acquisition_timer(self):
    zoom = self.m_ui.slider_zoom.value()/10
    self.__display.on_image_received(image_cpy, zoom)

The Display also use the wheelevent to enable zoom on the display. But each time the MainWindow send a new image, it also send the slider value, which cancel the wheel zoom.
I want the "wheel zoom" to also change the MainWindow slider position, but I don't know how to link those two. Can you explain me how to do that?
The Display class is:
class Display(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 1
        self.image_qt = QImage()
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.pic = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self.pic)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    def hasPicture(self):
        return not self._empty

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPicture():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom *= factor
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom *= factor
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)


    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def on_image_received(self, image: QImage, scale: float):
        self._zoom = scale
        self.image_qt = image

        # Image size
        image_width = self.image_qt.width()
        image_height = self.image_qt.height()

        # Return if we don't have an image yet
        if image_width == 0 or image_height == 0:
            return

        self._empty = False
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image_qt))
        self.fitInView()
        self.update()

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.pic.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPicture():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                factor *= self._zoom
                self.scale(factor, factor)

    @property
    def zoom(self):
        return self._zoom

